# Multithreaded write on MySQL DB with JDBC and c3p0

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, jdbc

I have written a DAO class which allows several threads invoked by `ExecutorServices` to write to MySQL DB.

**EDIT:** I am using c3p0 to create a JDBC ConnectionPool. So every new thread will get a new `JDBC Connection` by calling

```
DataBaseManager.getInstance().getConnection()
```

There seems to be random concurrency issue while executing, e.g:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
at com.eanurag.dao.DataBaseManager.writeData(DataBaseManager.java:102)
```

I am not able to understand all the issues with the code. Should I just synchronize entire `writeData()` ?

```
public class DataBaseManager {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DataBaseManager.class);

    private static volatile DataBaseManager dbInstance = null;

    private DataBaseManager() {
        cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            cpds.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            logger.error("Error in Initializing DB Driver class", e);
        }
        cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://" + DB_HOST + "/" + DB_NAME);
        cpds.setUser(DB_USER);
        cpds.setPassword(DB_PASS);

        cpds.setMinPoolSize(MINIMUM_POOL_SIZE);
        cpds.setAcquireIncrement(INCREMENT_SIZE);
        cpds.setMaxPoolSize(MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE);
        cpds.setMaxStatements(MAX_STATEMENTS);
    }

    public static DataBaseManager getInstance() {
        if (dbInstance == null) {
            synchronized (WorkerManager.class) {
                if (dbInstance == null) {
                    dbInstance = new DataBaseManager();
                }
            }
        }

        return dbInstance;
    }

    private ComboPooledDataSource cpds;

    private static final Integer MINIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 10;
    private static final Integer MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 1000;
    private static final Integer INCREMENT_SIZE = 5;
    private static final Integer MAX_STATEMENTS = 200;

    private volatile Connection connection = null;
    private volatile Statement statement = null;
    private volatile PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    private static final String DB_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final String DB_PORT = "3306";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASS = "";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "crawly";
    private static final String URL_TABLE = "url";


    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        logger.info("Creating connection to DB!");
        return this.cpds.getConnection();
    }

    public Boolean writeData(URL url) {
        StringBuffer writeDBStatement = new StringBuffer();
        writeDBStatement.append("insert into");
        writeDBStatement.append(" ");
        writeDBStatement.append(DB_NAME);
        writeDBStatement.append(".");
        writeDBStatement.append(URL_TABLE);
        writeDBStatement.append(" ");
        writeDBStatement.append("values (?,?,default)");

        Boolean dbWriteResult = false;

        try {
            connection = DataBaseManager.getInstance().getConnection();

                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(writeDBStatement.toString());
                preparedStatement.setString(1, url.getURL());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, String.valueOf(url.hashCode()));
                dbWriteResult = (preparedStatement.executeUpdate() == 1) ? true : false;


            if(dbWriteResult){
                logger.info("Successfully written to DB!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error("Error in writing to DB", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                preparedStatement.close();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return dbWriteResult;
    }


}
```

Comment: You access the member variables (Connection, PreparedStatement) from different Threads. Either make them method variables of writeData() or make sure each thread has own instance of your class.

Comment: I don't think `volatile` is going to give you the benefit you think it will there (not without some synchronization on `write` anyway). Why is the preparedstatement a class-level variable?

Comment: @Michal making (Connection, PreparedStatement) method variables of writeData(), as passing own instance of class to each thread will not work with the current logic of ConnectionPool. Thanks!

Comment: @kolossus My initial plan was to use PreparedStatement and Connection as class-level variable to reuse them across different methods (read(), write()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here?

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    logger.info("Creating connection to DB!");
    return this.cpds.getConnection();
}
```

Namely, what does cpds.getConnection() do?  When you call:

```
connection = DataBaseManager.getInstance().getConnection();
```

Your connection object is a member of what's supposed to be a singleton class here but every call to writeData() overwrites it it with a new getConnection() call.  Is the getConnection() call thread unsafe as well?

Also, why is the connection object declared as a class member and then overwritten each time writeData() is called?  In a multi-threaded environment, the code as it exists allows for the connection object to be overwritten by another getConnection() call immediately before prepareStatement() is called, since access to writeData() is not locked.  Same for preparedStatement.  Move those into the writeData() method.

Comment: So `cpds` is `ComboPooledDataSource`. This is the way of using c3p0 to create a JDBC connection pool. So here:

`connection = DataBaseManager.getInstance().getConnection();` will always return a new connection to the database.

Comment: Why is the connection object declared as a class member and then overwritten each time writeData() is called?  In a multi-threaded environment, the code as it exists allows for the connection object to be overwritten by another getConnection() call immediately before prepareStatement() is called, since access to writeData() is not locked.  Same for preparedStatement.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more? How is making Connection object a method variable solving the issue here? Multiple threads will access it at the same time as well.

Comment: When it is declared at the class level (as you have done) and then use the singleton pattern (as you have done), every call to writeData() allows the class member to be accessed.  Yes, you only have one instance of DataBaseManager.  But they all share the same connection and preparedStatement object.  If you move these variables into the writeData method, that will make it thread safe since only the caller will have access to it.

Answer (score 3):

The `connection` and `preparedStatement` variables must be local, not instance members.

No synchronization required.